# Substring part of a string

Tags: java, android, string

First, I want to excuse if this problem is already discussed and I'll be glad if you point me to an already answered question! I couldn't find one that will helps me out.

I have to extract only the last part after the last "/" in such a string:
/test/test2/test3

I have to extract only the "test3". But I cannot get to a way myself so I'm asking for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you need to isolate also the other parts of the string, this will be easiest way.

```
String s="a/b/c"; //Works also for "a b c" and "a/b/c/"
String[] parts=s.split("/");
System.out.println(parts[parts.length-1]);
```

Answer (score 15):

You just need to find the [last index of](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) `/`, and then take the [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) after that:

```
int lastIndex = text.lastIndexOf('/');
String lastPart = text.substring(lastIndex + 1);
```

(Other options exist, of course - regular expressions and splitting by `/` for example... but the above is what I'd do.)

Note that because we've got to use `+ 1` to get past the last `/`, this has the handy property that it still works even if there *aren't* any slashes:

```
String text = "no slashes here";
int lastIndex = text.lastIndexOf('/'); // Returns -1
String lastPart = text.substring(lastIndex + 1); // x.substring(0).equals(x)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Your answer helped me out! :)

Answer (score 10):

use [**String#lastIndexOf()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29)

```
"/test/test2/test3".substring("/test/test2/test3".lastIndexOf("/")+1)
```

Also assuming its a file path. you can also use [**File#getname()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29)

```
File f = new File("/test/test2/test3");
System.out.println(f.getName());
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Even though that I couldn't use it because I don't know the previous strings before the last "/". I appreciate your fast answer! :)